# Open an external program in Qt with an attached file extension

Tags: java, qt, qprocess

I am making a qt application which allows the user to select a file and then upon clicking ok, start the associated program with the file already loaded. The program I want to start is java based, and I know how to use QProcess to get it to open, I don't know however how to add the file extension which the user is selecting. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want the file to be open with the default program for that file extension, is that what you try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for leaving everyone hanging on this one, I actually solved this issue myself. Basically I just used QFileDialog to select my file I wanted to open and created a QString which was the entire command line I needed to use to get my application to run properly, which I opened via QProcess. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) ?

You can pass your program path and name as an Url (file:///) and it will be openned with a suitable application.